# Opening remote project in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-server

I'm working on a project that is located in a remote server. Can I open it in PyCharm from my local machine ? I couldn't find the way.

Answer (score 34):

The way I access the projects on my raspberry pi using PyCharm is the following  (This expects you to be using PyCharm Pro, supporting SSH connections):

1. Mount the home folder on my local machine ( I use [SFTP Drive](http://nsoftware.com/sftp/drive) on windows, under Linux use sshfs).
2. Open the project from the mounted drive in PyCharm
3. Go to Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter and select the gear next to the Project Interpreter drop down. From there pick "Add Remote".
4. Configure the remote interpreter you want to use.

#### If the PyCharm project was already created on the server, I guess your run configuration should be in order and running it should work out of the box.

#### If you created the PyCharm project on your local machine:

- If you have no run configuration yet, go to the file you want to run and do right-click -> Run yourfilename.py or simply hit Shift-F10
- The remote interpreter will complain about non existent files. Go to the dropdown in the top right corner, click it and select 'Edit Configurations'
- Change the script path and working directory to the actual remote directories. Remember, this is what your interpreter sees, and your interpreter is on your remote machine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When run a project on this setup, will my server resources (CPU, GPU, memory, etc.) be used?

Comment: The last line gives it away: "...and your interpreter is on your remote machine.", so yes, this will run the interpreter on your server, using your server's resources.

In fact, I originally used this to work remotely on my machine-learning-rig.

Comment: I found that `Sync with Deployed to...` also works fine (without need for a local mount), when the directory mappings are correctly set for the configured `Remote Host`.

Answer (score 5):

- The following will configure **PyCharm Professional 2021.3.1** on **Windows 10** to run a project on a remote Linux server. It's likely the configuration will be similar for PyCharm on macOS.

1. Open PyCharm
2. Create a <kbd>New Project</kbd> and select <kbd>Pure Python</kbd>
3. Fill the <kbd>Location</kbd> and <kbd>Remote project location</kbd>, which may be new or existing.
4. Select the ellipsis next to <kbd>Interpreter</kbd> under <kbd>Previously configured interpreter</kbd>
5. Select <kbd>SSH Interpreter</kbd> and create <kbd>New server connection</kbd>

   - Supply your credentials
   - The default <kbd>Interpreter</kbd> will be `/usr/bin/python`, but an alternate location may be provided, for example `/home/.../anaconda3/bin/python3.9`

     - [image]
   - [image]
6. <kbd>Create</kbd> the project
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open <kbd>Settings</kbd>

   1. Select <kbd>Deployment</kbd> under <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd>

      - Check <kbd>Connection</kbd> and <kbd>Test Connection</kbd>

        - [image]
      - Check <kbd>Mappings</kbd> to verify <kbd>Local path</kbd> and <kbd>Deployment path</kbd>

        - [image]
   2. Select <kbd>Python Interpreter</kbd> under <kbd>Project:...</kbd>

      - Verify the remote interpreter is selected for the project.

        - As long as this is the case, the code will run relative to the remote system.
      - [image]
   3. Close <kbd>Settings</kbd> with <kbd>OK</kbd>, or <kbd>Apply</kbd>
8. Use PUTTY or some other app to verify the project now exists on the remote system

   - [image]
9. Right click the project and select <kbd>Deployment</kbd> for deployment options

   - [image]

**Note**

- This will likely require being connected to the corporate network through a VPN.

Comment: At the risk of being redundant, deployment is not available in the community version of pycharm.

Answer (score 4):

To update on excellent @Skusku answer given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614111/2119941

After mounting remote folder with SFTP Drive if Pycharm project browser doesn't recognize remote drive just copy-paste it in location bar on top and allow Pycharm to load it:

[image]

And when you load your project files to Pycharm you need to add remote interpreter which is present on your server:

[image]

In following screens just add host, credentials and than path to python in virtual env or whatever python is running your server project files.

Answer (score 1):

Search remote sync under plugins in pycharm. Many work. I think most common one is [source sync.](https://github.com/fioan89/sourcesync/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Another alternative (tool outside of pycharm) is the Unison sync tool.  It runs as a stand-alone file sync program between two machines.

Answer (score 0):

Pycharm needs access to the project's directory.

You can open a remote project if the storage partition for that project directory is shared and  mounted/mapped on your local machine with the right permissions by running pycharm on your machine and opening that locally visible project directory.

**Note:** you should not be opening the project in multiple such pycharm sessions simultaneously as they will collide/conflict with each-other.

Alternatively if you use a version control system (VCS) that supports remote repository access you can create a local copy of the project, work in that copy and push your changes to the remote project as needed (depending on your VCS specifics).